# How to simplify the JSON returned by a query using PostgreSQL 15

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-json, postgresql-15

I am stuck with the PostgreSQL `json_build_object` function.
I am trying to build a query to return a JSON results like this:

```json
{
  "id": 1001,
  "is_active": true,
  "created_dt": "2023-04-22T14:37:37.985197",
  "updated_dt": "2023-04-22T14:37:37.985197",
  "author_id": 1004,
  "article_type": "TUTORIAL",
  "lang_code": "EN",
  "editorial_state": "DRAFT",
  "title": "Programming is fun!",
  "subtitle": "In this case, it is the third revision.",
  "published_dt": null,
  "is_eol": false,
  "is_featured": false,
  "is_front_page": false,
  "is_new": false,
  "is_onsale": false,
  "is_own": false,
  "is_top10": false,
  "is_top100": true,
  "bookmark_count": 3,
  "clap_count": 43,
  "reading_count": 14,
  "share_count": 2,
  "view_count": 498,
  "rel_articles": [
    {
      "id": 1001,
      "article_type": "TUTORIAL",
      "lang_code": "EN",
      "title": "Programming is fun!",
      "reading_time": 0.00,
      "word_count": 0,
      "subtitle": "In this case, it is the third revision."
    },
    {
      "id": 1018,
      "article_type": "ARTICLE",
      "lang_code": "EN",
      "title": "ARTICLE-1018-EN",
      "reading_time": 0.00,
      "word_count": 0,
      "subtitle": null
    },
    {
      "id": 1023,
      "article_type": "TUTORIAL",
      "lang_code": "EN",
      "title": "ARTICLE-1023-EN",
      "reading_time": 0.00,
      "word_count": 0,
      "subtitle": null
    }
  ]
}
```

However, some extra naming `article` and `json_agg` are being added to the returned string:

```json
{
  "article": {
    "id": 1001,
    "is_active": true,
    "created_dt": "2023-04-22T14:37:37.985197",
    "updated_dt": "2023-04-22T14:37:37.985197",
    "author_id": 1004,
    "article_type": "TUTORIAL",
    "lang_code": "EN",
    "editorial_state": "DRAFT",
    "title": "Programming is fun!",
    "subtitle": "In this case, it is the third revision.",
    "published_dt": null,
    "is_eol": false,
    "is_featured": false,
    "is_front_page": false,
    "is_new": false,
    "is_onsale": false,
    "is_own": false,
    "is_top10": false,
    "is_top100": true,
    "bookmark_count": 3,
    "clap_count": 43,
    "reading_count": 14,
    "share_count": 2,
    "view_count": 498
  },
  "rel_articles": {
    "json_agg": [
      {
        "id": 1001,
        "article_type": "TUTORIAL",
        "lang_code": "EN",
        "title": "Programming is fun!",
        "reading_time": 0.00,
        "word_count": 0,
        "subtitle": "In this case, it is the third revision."
      },
      {
        "id": 1018,
        "article_type": "ARTICLE",
        "lang_code": "EN",
        "title": "ARTICLE-1018-EN",
        "reading_time": 0.00,
        "word_count": 0,
        "subtitle": null
      },
      {
        "id": 1023,
        "article_type": "TUTORIAL",
        "lang_code": "EN",
        "title": "ARTICLE-1023-EN",
        "reading_time": 0.00,
        "word_count": 0,
        "subtitle": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The query is this:

```sql
with json_article as (
  select
    tj.*
  from (
    select
      ta.*,
      /* language */
            tx.lang_code,
      tx.editorial_state,
      tx.title,
      tx.subtitle,
      tx.published_dt,
      /* facts */
      tf.is_eol,
      tf.is_featured,
      tf.is_front_page,
      tf.is_new,
      tf.is_onsale,
      tf.is_own,
      tf.is_top10,
      tf.is_top100,
      tf.bookmark_count,
      tf.clap_count,
      tf.reading_count,
      tf.share_count,
      tf.view_count        
    from 
      cnt_article ta
    left join
      cnt_doc_title tx on tx.doc_id = ta.id and tx.doc_type = 'ARTICLE' and  
      tx.lang_code = 'EN'
    left join
      cnt_doc_fact tf on tf.doc_id = ta.id and tf.doc_type = 'ARTICLE'
    where 
      ta.id = 1001
  ) as tj
), json_rel_articles as (
    select
      json_agg(row_to_json(trel))
    from (
      select
        tr.doc2_id as id,
        ta.article_type,
        tx.lang_code,
        tx.title,
        tx.reading_time,
        tx.word_count,
        tx.subtitle
      from 
        cnt_doc_relation tr
      left join
        cnt_doc_title tx on tx.doc_id = tr.doc2_id and tx.doc_type = tr.doc2_type and 
        tx.lang_code = 'EN'
      left join
        cnt_article ta on ta.id = tr.doc2_id
      where 
        tr.doc1_type = 'ARTICLE' and tr.doc1_id = 1001 and tr.relation_type = 'REF' and 
        tr.doc2_type = 'ARTICLE'
    ) as trel
)
select
  json_build_object(
    'article',
    json_article,
    'rel_articles',
    json_rel_articles
    )
from
  json_article, json_rel_articles;
```

The "article" braces are my fault, as `json_build_object` requires keys and values. The "json_agg" is something I don't understand. I suppose I have to avoid using `json_build_object`, but I am clueless of what to use instead.

Any idea of how to modify the query to produce the required output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1.  Do not mix subqueries and CTEs.  2.  Use jsonb instead of json.  3.  Instead of `json_build_object()` or `jsonb_build_object(), use `to_jsonb()`.  4.  The `json_agg` key appears in your result because you did not alias the column.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE head(i INTEGER);
INSERT INTO head VALUES   (1),   (2),   (3);

CREATE TABLE details(i INTEGER, c CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO details VALUES
   (1,'a'),   (1,'b'),   (1,'c'),
   (2,'d'),   (2,'e'),   (2,'f'),
   (3,'g'),   (3,'h'),   (3,'i');
```

A Simplified example, with these simple tables:

```
SELECT 
   JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('head', i, 
                     'details',(SELECT JSON_AGG(c) 
                                FROM details 
                                WHERE details.i = head.i)
                    )
FROM head
WHERE i=2;
```

returns:

```
{"head" : 2, "details" : ["d", "e", "f"]}
```

The explanation is in the docs... (somewhere).

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/r1wYy9Xa)

Comment: This is not equivalent to the OP. Only the column `c` is being aggregated to the JSON array. JSON objects as `{"i":1, "c":"a"}` should appear.